# Animate class add/remove via scroll position in real time?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

My goal is to animate the addition/removal of a class in real time depending on the scroll position. In this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcompt/3w8xft7L/1/) the red box with the blue border changes to the yellow box with the purple border when the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page. I like that but what I want to happen is for that transition to be linked to the scroll position and to happen in real time as the scroll bar is moved down. So it will be a fade effect whose speed and position is determined by the scroll bar position. How does one do this? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST SITE ONE</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test Site">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>

    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    display: block;
}


.box1{
position: fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
max-width: 100%;
background-color: red;
border: 2vw solid blue;
}

.box1add{
    background-color: gold;
    border: 2vw solid purple;
}


.box2{

position: absolute;
height: 200vh;
width: 25vw;
background-color: orange;
border: 2vw solid green;
margin-left: 37.5vw;
margin-right: 37.5vw;

}
</style>


    <script>
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     //console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= $(window).height()) {
        //console.log('a');
        $(".box1").addClass("box1add");
    } else {
        //console.log('a');
        $(".box1").removeClass("box1add");
    }
});
    </script>


<body>

<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To start with, query the DOM for class elements - on every scroll tick - is such a bad idea. Cache your selectors.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you but can point you in the right direction. In order to do this you'll need to calculate the exact scroll position on the page and use this value to adjust an hsl or rgb value accordingly. Here is an updated fiddle where I've demonstrated this by essentially transitioning from black to white for the border color: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8xft7L/7/